# Django Model, Multi value / Admin Area

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have start fresh with Django.
I am creating a blog and I need a hint now.
I want to add tags to my posts.
So I created a model for my tags:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is my Post Model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

What is the best way, that the user can select in the admin area tags for the post and more than one or create a new tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Post class， add a field ManyToMany

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: notice when using many-to-many field name should be plural - tags  -> style reasons

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [InlineModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) particulary section regarding
[Working with many-to-many models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models)

something as following:

```
class TagInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Post.tags.through

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        TagInline,
    ]
```

Also you are missing relationship on your model which should be [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```